# equation double pointer to NULL gives segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

typedef struct Node {
 int data;
 struct Node * next;
} Node;


void push(Node **headRef, int i){
//why does headRef == NULL in below if condition gives segmentation fault?
  if(*headRef == NULL){
    *headRef = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *head = *headRef;
    head->data = i;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  Node *head = NULL;
  push(&head, 2);
  printf("%d\n", head->data);
}
```

This code is of linked list where I try to push some data into the list.
My question is in the comment of push function.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that line.

Comment: In standard C, `malloc` lives in `<stdlib.h>`, not `<malloc.h>`. I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Other than that, your code runs fine. Your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Same here. Code compiles and prints `2`.

Comment: Are you sure that is the line that is failing? Try stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: It only gives a segmentation fault if you change `(*headRef == NULL)` to `(headRef == NULL)` (note the absence of star). Then, `head->data` causes a segfault.

Comment: Can only concur, besides your code not setting the next pointer to null (which will cause problems later on), I can't see a problem.

Comment: The only case for a segfault I can see is if `malloc()` returns NULL for some reason (yeah, it does occur, so it is best to check). But it is very unlikely.

Comment: You should be setting `head->next = NULL;` in your function, or otherwise initializing it.  However, not doing so is not (yet) causing your crash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, segfault is later at `head->data` access (if you use `headRef==NULL`)

Comment: in the code change *headRef== NULL with headRef == NULL, then there is a segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

No need for the test. If *headRef happens to be NULL, newnode->next will be set to NULL, otherwise to *headRef.

```
void push(Node **headRef, int i){
    Node *new;

    new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    /* check for new==NULL omitted */
    new->next = *headRef;
    new->data = i;
    *headRef = new;
 }
```